# Error in Postgres TX

Tags: postgresql

Trying to create a user in the database and it's telling me that `cannot execute **** in a read-only transaction`. I have no idea what's causing this? Is this a bad state in the database or connection? Why is this telling that it's not in a transaction but then telling me it's a read-only transaction? Does "transaction" refer to the same thing?

```
$ psql --host localhost --port 5432 --username **** postgres --no-password -v dbuser=root -t -X
psql (10.1, server 9.4.13)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# set transaction read write;
WARNING:  SET TRANSACTION can only be used in transaction blocks
ERROR:  cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery
postgres=# CREATE USER root WITH PASSWORD 'root';
ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE ROLE in a read-only transaction
```

Comment: This may help you https://serverfault.com/questions/630753/how-to-change-postgresql-database-from-read-only-to-writable

Comment: Are you trying to execute on a replica?

Comment: I'm using stolon and the problem ended up being that I was pointing to the wrong port. The other port was mapped to another container that seemed to work as a replica and no a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is in recovery.

Either it is a hot standby (most likely), or recovery was paused with `SELECT pg_wal_replay_pause()` or `recovery_target_action = 'pause'` in `recovery.conf` (check with `SELECT pg_is_wal_replay_paused()`), or a point-in-time-recovery is still running.

Use the primary or complete recovery.